# Disable just tapping on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, ontouchlistener, gesturedetector

I have a ViewPager which scrolls through emails, it requests an email when the user stops scrolling for a brief amount of time, with a scheduler.

During this pause I don't want any of the placeholder buttons that are on the page being loaded from being clicked.  During this paging event, therefore I would like to allow swiping, since the user can keep swiping to a different email but disable tapping on sender / receiver or interactive elements within the email which are still placeholder and will lead nowhere.

I have tried to do something like this so far on the view pager:

```
// Set a simple gesture to handle our click request, allowing everything else
final GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener dsl_simpleDetector = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    public boolean onSingleTapUp (MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        // Don't want to do anything with this if timer is running
        final ExchangeEmailActivity ds_act = (ExchangeEmailActivity) getActivity();
        if (ds_act.dsc_timer != null) { // We're waiting for the page to load still
            return false; // Handle it by doing nothing
        } else {
            return true; // Let it be handled as necessary
        }
    }
};

// The listener will call the simple gesture above to handle it
vp_pager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return (dsl_simpleDetector.onSingleTapUp(motionEvent));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want your users to click a button -> **disable the button**. 
It is bad design to "hack" the touch listener to just prevent a user from clicking buttons.

Comment: It is not viable to interact with the buttons themselves, they're part of a broader system, hacking them would be much worse design.  The ViewPager is the shallowest system of them all, and the functionality should only pertain to that particular ViewPager, none other.

Comment: It can ofc be that the ViewPager is the shallowest system. BUT you have to see it from user view. If there are enabled buttons(which you prevent from being clicked) in your app a user will try to click them sooner or later and nothing will happen. And that should never happen.

Comment: In this case it seems acceptable to do so since this disabling functionality should only last about 200 milliseconds, a toast message could be provided when intercepting this functionality having the ViewPager inform the user to await completion of loading.